# Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-jdbc

i am attempting to delete one record by passing 2 column as filter using Spring jdbctemplate. But i do not know what is the wrong with below code. I have mentioned exception below. i have checked in dedug, requestId and qtId values are coming.

```
public void deleteTxn(String sql, int requestId, int qtId) {
    try {
            jdbcTemplate.update(sql,
                    new Object[]{
                    requestId,
                    qtId
                    }); 
        } catch(Exception e) {
            //
        }
    }
}

String sql = "DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE COL1 = ? AND COL2 = ?";
```

**Exception :**

> org.springframework.jdbc.InvalidResultSetAccessException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; invalid ResultSet access for SQL [DELETE
>   FROM TABLE1 WHERE COL1 = ? AND COL2 = ?]; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index   at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:235)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:660)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:909)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:970)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:980)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jdbcTemplate.update` has two similar method signatures:

- `update(java.lang.String sql, java.lang.Object... args)`
- `update(java.lang.String sql, java.lang.Object[] args, int[] argTypes)`.

In your case the first overloaded method is chosen because you didn't provide `int[] argTypes`, and hence your update statement has only one argument, which is `new Object[]{requestId, qtId}`.

The solution is simple: just write `jdbcTemplate.update(sql, requestId, qtId);`

Or, if you want to provide types, something like this:

```
jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[]{requestId, qtId}, 
                         new int[]{Types.BIGINT, Types.BIGINT});
```